# Emacs Chinese Font is strange when upgrading to OSX 10.9

Tags: emacs

My font is Source Code Pro-14

[image: Current font]

[image: Old font]

The only difference is that I upgrade my system from OSX 10.8.5 to OSX 10.9.

Chinese font retains same even after changing the font to other fonts.

Comment: I am thinking the problem is probably your fallback font in OSX. `Source Code Pro` has no Chinese character, so the system will fallback to other fonts until it find one. That setting is probably changed after you upgrade.

Comment: I got this problem too

Comment: @C.C. You can see my answer. Updated for English system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code solved my problem:

```lisp
(set-face-attribute
  'default nil :font "Source Code Pro 14")
(set-fontset-font
    (frame-parameter nil 'font)
    'han
    (font-spec :family "宋体" :size 14))
```

Or if you are using an English system, try following:

```lisp
(set-fontset-font t 'han (font-spec :name "Songti SC"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The font Source Code Pro may not have the glyph that you wish to have rendered.  There is one quick way around this.  Try `M-x describe-char` which will pop up a buffer describing the character displayed, its name, codepoint and which font it is using to display the character.

In many font systems, if a glyph isn't available in a given fontset, there will be fallback fonts used instead.  I suspect that for you, the fallback fonts have changed under the hood in the OS and that is why you see the difference.  It is likely that Source Code Pro has nothing to do with it.

Additionally, you can type `M-x describe-fontset` in your buffer to see which unicode ranges map to which fonts.  This may also help you pinpoint the differences.